# Strange error caused by some weird interaction

Tags: errors

The following short document prints a scoresheet for a simple dice game called kinderyahtzee.  It is close to what I want:

```
%%%%% Kinder-yatzee scoresheet in \LaTeX
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,pdftex,active,tightpage,multi=true]{standalone}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}%%%%%Extended, modernized version of tabular
\usepackage{epsdice}%%%%%\epsdice command
\usepackage{igo} %%%%% circled numbers
%%%%% Defining commands for yatzee names:
%% If using epsdice, we need:
\newcommand{\Cube}[1]{\raisebox{-1.2pt}{\epsdice{#1}}}   
\newcommand{\two}{\whitestone[2]}
\newcommand{\three}{\whitestone[3]}
\newcommand{\four}{\whitestone[4]}
\newcommand{\five}{\whitestone[5]}
\newcommand{\six}{\whitestone[6]}
\newcommand{\seven}{\whitestone[7]}
\newcommand{\eight}{\whitestone[8]}
\newcommand{\nine}{\whitestone[9]}
\newcommand{\ten}{\whitestone[10]}
\newcommand{\eleven}{\whitestone[11]}
\newcommand{\twelve}{\whitestone[12]}
\newcommand{\titleline}{\Large\textsc{Barneyatzy}}
\dimen0=0.6cm{}
\newcommand{\onesheet}{% code for typesetting one score sheet
{\hspace*{1cm}
{\begin{tabular}[t]{||p{2\dimen0}|p{\dimen0}|p{\dimen0}|p{\dimen0}|p{\dimen0}|p{\dimen0}|p{\dimen0}|p{\dimen0}|p{\dimen0}|p{\dimen0}|p{\dimen0}|p{\dimen0}|p{\dimen0}|p{\dimen0}|p{\dimen0}|p{\dimen0}|p{\dimen0}||}\firsthline   \hline
             & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &      \\   \hline
\two         & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &      \\   \hline   
\three       & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &      \\   \hline 
\four        & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &      \\   \hline 
\five        & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &      \\   \hline 
\six         & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &      \\   \hline 
\seven       & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &      \\   \hline 
\eight       & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &      \\   \hline 
\nine        & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &      \\   \hline 
\ten         & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &      \\   \hline 
\eleven      & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &      \\   \hline 
\twelve      & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &      \\   \hline    \lasthline  
\end{tabular}}}
}%%%%% End \onesheet
\begin{document}
%\vspace*{1.5cm}{} %%%%% This line destroys the document! Why?
\titleline  \\[1ex] 
\onesheet   \\[4ex]
\onesheet   \\[4ex]   
\onesheet   \newpage
\vspace*{2cm}
\hspace*{1cm}
\parbox{0.7\textwidth}{Spilleregler:  Barna kaster med to vanlige terninger, summerer øynene
som gir et resultat fra 2 opp til tolv.  Kryss av for det man fikk,
kast igjen. Den vinner som først får krysset av alle mulighetene!   }
\end{document}
```

But when I uncomment the first line after \begin{document}  the effect is not close to what I want, for instance a new vertical line is printed down the first column in the table,  over the numbers!?  What is going on.

I think I can get what I want in some other way, the most important for me is somme explanation of what is going on!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's quite simple. You're misusing `\dimen0` not just as a temporary storage bin. The command `\vspace` uses `\dimen0` so your setting is lost.

The value of `\dimen0` is not computed when `\onesheet` is defined, just `\dimen0` is remembered and, at usage time, the *current* value will be used.

Say

```
\newdimen\cellwidth
\cellwidth=0.6cm
```

and use `\cellwidth` where you have `\dimen0`.